# install debian package with change configuration

Tags: php, debian, apt-get

I need to install php5 source debian package with zend thread safety enable (ZTS=1)
but in default this config is disable.
how can rebuild package with my configuration ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Download and extract package sources with `apt-get source php5`
2. Edit `debian/rules` file and add `--enable-roxen-zts` or `--enable-maintainer-zts` to COMMON_CONFIG (confirm which one you need with `./configure --help`).
3. `sudo apt-get build-dep php5` to install build dependencies.
4. From directory where package source were extracted run `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b`.

Optionally if you have `devscripts` package installed you may run `debuild -uc -b` instead of `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b`.

Comment: I followed this exact sequence and ended up with rougly 20 .deb packages. I then dbl-clicked the PHP5 meta-package and when checking phpinfo I got `Thread Safety  disabled`. I don't know what went wrong. I added the `--enable-maintainer-zts` to my `rules` files but nada. Should I add `--enable-roxen-zts` too and recompile ?? Thanks.

Comment: I would just like to note that if you already have MySQL installed, you may get an error like this: ERROR: 1005  Can't create table 'db' (errno: 13) the resolution was to set RUN_TESTS = no in debian/rules

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However the build seems to loop for me - it is building php 6+ times and has been looping for over an hour. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: @Bas Kuis This is because php compiles for every possible SAPI e.g. fpm, cli, apache2 etc

Answer (score -3):

Dont worry, it really takes a long time for the package build, and it also looks like it is in loop, but it will come to an end, eventually.